# TypeError from importing discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I just installed the discord.py rewrite branch, but attempting to use `import discord` or `from discord.ext import commands` simply results in a TypeError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .guild import Guild
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .channel import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .webhook import Webhook
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/webhook.py", line 27, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import *  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import connector as connector_mod
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .client_proto import ResponseHandler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client_proto.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .http import HttpResponseParser, StreamWriter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/http.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .http_parser import (HttpParser, HttpRequestParser, HttpResponseParser,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/http_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .http_writer import HttpVersion, HttpVersion10
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/http_writer.py", line 304, in <module>
    class URL(yarl.URL):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/__init__.py", line 232, in __init_subclass__
    "is forbidden".format(cls))
TypeError: Inheritance a class <class 'aiohttp.http_writer.URL'> from URL is forbidden
```

Although the error is technically from yarl rather than from discord.py itself, the error only occurs upon trying to import the modules.

I've already tried reinstalling python as well as the discord.py rewrite branch, and if it makes any difference am running on a RPi 3 B+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Inheritance a class from URL is forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165167/typeerror-inheritance-a-class-from-url-is-forbidden)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your aiohttp package might be out of date.

Try

```
pip install --upgrade aiohttp
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I was originally going to do that but it stated that discordpy needed an older version of aiohttp

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install discord.py on my python 3.7 and it didn't work.

I had to install python 3.6.6 to make it work, maybe you are using python 3.7, if so you should try rolling back to python 3.6.6